# How to select lines/polygons in QGIS CAD tool?

Tags: qgis, cad

I'm intending to create parallel and orthogonal lines by using the CAD tool in QGIS.

For each tool there is a button to select the feature before executing the tool.

But though I fixed all the snapping properties - as far as I think - correctly, the tool will neither snap nor select the focused lines or polygons.

Is there anyone who has to face the same Problem and could help me out of this?

In the screenshot the selection button for the parallel lines tool is indicated by the red arrow.

[image]

---

the missing Picture i mentioned before...[image: cad tool]

Answer (score 1):

First, the tool has been designed to work in 'no editing mode'. Second, the 'snapping properties' are automatically related to selected and existing features. You don't need to select them in snapping properties of QGIS. Third, if you have created new features (Cad Layer Points o Cad Layer Lines) you should select them for automatically work with the 'new snapping conditions'. For example:

1) Orthogonal line and intersection point (observe that the first vertex is quite different):

[image]

Result:

[image]

2) Creating a parallel line to top edge of **square_zone** and snap to vertex in **Cad Layer Points**:

[image]

Result:

[image]

It works intuitively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but though i tried it several times, the features don't show any Vertices to select while the selection (for example of the "orthogonal line" tool) is enabled. In the picture, the cursor is at the position of the red arrow (the cursor was not saved by the snapshot). The only selection I can get is from the "rotate feature" tool, however it's only possible to select one feature, which in this case is not enough. The point I'm interested in is how I can select the features/verices, the rest - i agree with you - should work intuitively.